# enable/disable multiple text boxes on dropdown selection values in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have 1 drop-down which contains values("Due Date","Tenure","NA". these values come from database) respectively.I have 2 text boxes textbox1 and textbox 2. I want `textbox1`(i.e `DueDate`) enabled if Dropdown value selected as "`Due Date`" & textbox2(i.e.`TenureDate`) enabled if Dropdown value selected as "`Tenure`".

```
<div>
     @Html.DropdownListFor(m=>m.Tenure,new{ng_options="c 
                            as c.name for c in duedateddl"})
</div>
<div>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.DueDate)
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.TenureDate)
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide full code. With correct editing

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('ngrepeatSelect', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
     model: null,
     availableOptions: [
       {name: 'DueDate'},
       {name: 'TenureDate'},
       {name: 'NA'}
     ]
    };
 }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  

  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="ngrepeatSelect">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="repeatSelect"> Repeat select: </label>
    <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.model">
      <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" value="{{option.name}}">{{option.name}}</option>
    </select>
    
    <input type="textBox1" ng-disabled="data.model != 'DueDate'"/>
    <input type="textBox2" ng-disabled="data.model != 'TenureDate'"/>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <tt>model = {{data.model}}</tt><br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```